# Android google maps use GPS location NOT network

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

In my application I want to get the location of the user and show it on a map (google maps).
In the settings of a android device you can check

1. Use Wireless networks
2. Use GPS satellites

When the user starts the mapactivity I show a dialog in wich the user can choose to get his current location or not.

```
Old code deleted
```

If the user wants to get his location I check if the gps is enabled. If not, I start the settings. Else I try to get the location. But even when GPS is active and "use wireless networks" not he won't get a location. Is there a solution to check if "Use wireless networks" is enabled. Or what part of my code I need to change to get location only by GPS signal?

Thanks

EDIT mycurrentcode:

```
boolean isGps = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                boolean isNetwork = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if(!isGps && !isNetwork){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if(isGps && !isNetwork) {
                    String bestProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);


                    Toast.makeText(MapsTabActivitiy.this, "Location niet beschikbaar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(!isGps && isNetwork) {
                    String bestProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

                    if(location == null){
                        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    } else if (location != null){
                        mapcontroller.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6)));
                        mapcontroller.setZoom(15);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                    String bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

                    if(location == null){
                        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    } else if (location != null){
                        mapcontroller.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6)));
                        mapcontroller.setZoom(15);
                    }
                }
```

So I check with isProviderEnabled for GPS_PROVIDER AND NETWORK_PROVIDER. And with the if, else if I change how to get the location. The only case I need to find is case 2 (else if(isGps && !isNetwork){}). Get the location by GPS signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the right provider using the `Criteria` class, but you can simple use the `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` to request the location updates using only GPS. Change

```
String bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
```

to

```
String bestProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope now he doesn't find my location even when "use wireless networks" is checked

Comment: @TimonDevos, And is "use gps satellites" checked?

Comment: But I want the device to choose wich location is more accurate at runtime. If i use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER then the device doesn't choose? It's only when NETWORK_PROVIDER isn't enabled he needs to get the location from GPS¨PROVIDER and vice versa

Comment: @TimonDevos, You can use the LocationManager.isProviderEnabled() method to identify if a provider is currently available. Use it along with the Criteria class to find the most accurate provider that is currently available.

Comment: Is it possible that it takes a while to get the location via GPS?

Comment: @TimonDevos, It usually takes time.